# MySql Access VB

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

```
My application is
Microsoft Access front end
MySql back end
Code is in vb
```

I am trying to modify a form that has a few drop down fields [![enter image description here][1]][1]. I need it to require the **jobcustomerID** before updating.  Right now if i add an address first it will tell me to add the customer but gives me an error for "invalid use of null"

Current Code

```
    Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
       If IsNull(Me.JobCustomerID) Or Me.JobCustomerID = "" Then
            Call MsgBox("You must select a Customer from the list provided", vbExclamation, "REQUIRED ENTRY")
             Me.JobCustomerID.SetFocus
             Cancel = True
             Exit Sub
           End If
       End Sub
```

I do have an image of the fields but lack the reputation needed

Comment: if the front end is in access it is not VB.NET, but access-vba

Comment: Thank you
I am still familiarizing myself with the system that is in place

Comment: Assuming JobCustomerID is the drop down control, it might be easiest just to disable the dependent controls, only enabling them once one has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the cancellation to the front.

```
If IsNull(Me.JobCustomerID) Or Me.JobCustomerID = "" Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "You must select a Customer from the list provided", vbExclamation, "REQUIRED ENTRY"
    Me.JobCustomerID.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```